# Decrypt Secure Strings in Windows DPAPI using Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, dpapi

Given a Windows DPAPI file with values stored as Secure Strings How would one decrypt those values in Python? The secure string is created with PowerShell like this.

```
$global:Credentials.AuthToken = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Auth-Token:"
```

and these values are stored using DPAPI on a Windows 10 or similar Computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python extract the Secure String from the DPAPI file and feed it to the function below. The secure string will be stored as a base64 encoded value.

***Note: when you read the DPAPI file created by PowerShell ensure you use "utf-16-le" encoding.***

```
import codecs
import win32crypt
import base64
        
def decrypt(b64string):

   b64decodedstring = base64.b64decode(b64string)

   clear = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(b64decodedstring, None, None, None, 0)

   return clear[1].decode("utf-16-le")
```

For a secure string in Windows the value is stored on disk as a base64 encoded hex. So extract the clear text value like this running it through the function twice with an encode of the hex value back to base64 in between.

```
decrypt(codecs.encode(codecs.decode(decrypt(ValueExtractedFromDPAPIGoesHere), 'hex'), 'base64').decode())
```

***Note: you will need to run Python as the user whose DPAPI you are trying to access the secure strings from.***